# Specific Redirect/Rewrite Rule for web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Can someone assist with a redirect rule?

I would like to swap any occurrence of, say, "newjersey", anywhere in the url for "new-jersey".

Any suggestions on how to do this via web.config would be great, as I need to do this right away. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working via the following:

```
<rule name="Redirect {1}/newjersey" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/newjersey$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/new-jersey" appendQueryString="false" />
```